# Python multiprocessing - watch a process and restart it when fails

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Consider this **working** code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from updaters import app1, app2

if __name__ == '__main__':

    apps = [ app1, app2]  
    for app in apps:
        instance = app()
        p = Process(target=instance.start_listener)
        p.start()
        p.join()
```

This works fine until one process fails (lets say some exception) - how Can I programmatically monitor the process and restart it if it fails

Comment: Note that since join() had no timeout and is blocking you will run your processes one after the other which is not what I *think* you are trying to do.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Poll the Process.is_alive() and if it returns False delete the process and start a new one, e.g.:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from updaters import app1, app2
from time import sleep

if __name__ == '__main__':

    apps = [app1, app2]  
    processes = {}
    n = 0
    for app in apps:
        instance = app()
        p = Process(target=instance.start_listener)
        p.start()
        processes[n] = (p, app) # Keep the process and the app to monitor or restart
        n += 1

    while len(processes) > 0:
        for n in processes.keys():
            (p, a) = processes[n]
            sleep(0.5)
            if p.exitcode is None and not p.is_alive(): # Not finished and not running
                 # Do your error handling and restarting here assigning the new process to processes[n]
                 print(a, 'is gone as if never born!')
            elif p.exitcode < 0:
                print ('Process Ended with an error or a terminate', a)
                # Handle this either by restarting or delete the entry so it is removed from list as for else
            else:
                print (a, 'finished')
                p.join() # Allow tidyup
                del processes[n] # Removed finished items from the dictionary 
                # When none are left then loop will end
print ('FINISHED')
```

Comment: Thanks @steve. can you please elaborate with a code example? where so I poll and how?

Comment: Steve: The first `for` loop needs to increment `n` after assigning to `processes[n]`. @alonisser: The running processes are stored in the `processes` dict. To "poll" it you could nest the last `for` loop inside a `while processes:` if you made the `p.exitcode < 0:` clause delete anything it doesn't/can't restart.

Comment: I can't believe that people are still suggesting busy waiting solutions.

Comment: what is 'a' here? Did you mean to type 'app'?

Comment: a it's not app. a is assigned on this line: `(p, a) = processes[n]`

Comment: a is the app as stored in the processes dictionary by `processes[n] = (p, app)` and **retrieved** by `(p, a) = processes[n]`

Comment: @SteveBarnes Hi, can I ask if you start a process `b = multiprocessing.Process(target=openpic)` and the process ends resulting in `is_alive() = False` can you simply `del b` and redo the above if you would like to restart the process or will there be "zombie" process left over? Thanks!

Comment: @Josh you should either call wait on the process or ignore the SIGCHLD signal to avoid leaving defunct (zombie) child processes in the system. After that you can simply assign the new Process to a new variable.